# Stack Exchange Annual hacking

Tags: discussion

Do we REALLY have to have this childish prank each year?

This is hardly encouraging responsible adult behaviour.

Comment: I understand that this is a thing across the whole Stackexchange network. *They* did not ask *us* so there is little to do about that on this particular stack. You might want to take the issue to MSE where it is being discussed at length already, say here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325996/284388

Comment: Though I have to admit that comic sans is hard on my eyes too and I wonder if *they* somehow forgot to reverse the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After avoiding the site for a couple of days (the iOS app didn't seem to be infected) I searched Meta and found how to turn this ridiculous waste of time off - by clicking the clock icon.